# Toolbar with PreferenceActivity app:theme is not working

Tags: android, android-theme, android-toolbar

I am adding toolbar with PreferenceActivity using following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/actionbar_color"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    app:navigationContentDescription="@string/abc_action_bar_up_description"
    app:navigationIcon="?attr/homeAsUpIndicator"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:theme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
```

**Code Snippet:**

```
LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout) findViewById(android.R.id.list).getParent().getParent().getParent();
        Toolbar bar = (Toolbar) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.app_bar_settings, root, false);
        root.addView(bar, 0); // insert at top
```

It is successfully showing the Toolbar with PreferenceActivity
but actionbar up arrow, title and action overflow button is black in color, according to my Theme `app:theme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar`
these should be white in color. How do i solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

By accessing navigation icon from toolbar we can change color

```
toolbar.getNavigationIcon().setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

if it's not working try this

```
toolbar.getNavigationIcon().mutate().setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```